# Using Angular 6 ngFor, how to change some content on comparing with other array of data?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-template

I am creating shopping cart. I have array of object for products data and array of cart item data. I try to build button to buy item, having conditional button, if same product in cart data then need to show '+ 3 -'(quantity comes from cart data by Id) and if product not in cart then simply show 'buy' button. This related problem I have implemented on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-267ern.

I try to solve with:

1. pipe,
2. trackBy,
3. Try to change product array data map and return values comparing with cart data (this is for trying to get solution but I couldn't). Here bu using pipe may have some problem over complexity (n*2).

So looking solution for less complexity and at least solution for this problem. If possible do care of complexity.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your problem, is this what you want?

In the TS (copied it from the stackblitz)

```
 export class AppComponent {
      products :product[]= [
        { name: 'Radio', price: 34, _id: '12345' },
        { name: 'TV', price: 44, _id: '12346' },
        { name: 'Bascket', price: 16, _id: '12347' },
        { name: 'Banana', price: 4, _id: '12348' },
        { name: 'Bike', price: 5000, _id: '12349' },
        { name: 'Toast', price: 5, _id: '12350' },
        { name: 'Shirt', price: 17, _id: '12351' }
      ];
    isCart (id){
    return this.cart.findIndex((x)=>x._id == id)>=0;
    }
    quantity(id){
    return this.cart.find((x)=>x._id == id).quantity;
    }
    buy(prod:product){
  if(this.cart.findIndex((x)=>x._id == prod._id)<0){
this.cart.push({name:prod.name,price:prod.price,_id:prod._id,quantity:1})
  }else{ 
let prod1 = this.cart.find((x)=>x._id == prod._id);
prod1.quantity +=1;
  }

}
      cart = [
        { name: 'Radio', price: 34, _id: '12345', quantity: 5 },
        { name: 'Toast', price: 5, _id: '12350', quantity: 1 },
      ]
    }
    export interface product{
    name:string;
    price:number;
    _id:string;
    }
```

and in HTML:

```
<label *ngFor="let item of products">
  <span>
      <p>Name: {{item?.name}}, Price: {{item?.price}}</p>
  </span>
  <button  (click)="buy(item)">
    <span>{{isCart(item._id)?quantity(item._id)+'-':'Buy'}} 
  </span>
  </button>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I am not sure wether it helps in when it add more item and cart item data refresh. Could you please suggest method for dynamic changes with data like after adding one more data and refresh cart item data, and shouldn't reload page. You method works fine for static data. I try it with dynamic changes with data. If and problem I will ping you.

Comment: @VikasKumar I changed the code you can now add items to cart.

Comment: have you consider complexity for your solution? Because I am searching for solution having less complexity.